# libcurl - использование cookie`сов

Tags: c, curl

Вопрос по поводу параметра `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookies.txt");
```

То есть, этот параметр говорит либкурлу при новом HTTP запросе на сервер сначала проверить ранее записанные куки из указанного файла.

Меня немного смущает вот это обьяснение:

> If you use this option multiple times, you just add more file**s** to
> read. Subsequent file**s** will add more cookies.
>
> Если вы используете эту опцию несколько раз, вы просто добавляете
> больше файлов для чтения. Последующие файлы будут добавлять файлы
> cookie.

Не могу понять, о каких файлах идет речь? Почему во множественном числе?

Я пробовал использовать ее несколько раз, но указывал один и тот же файл и либкурл записывал туда куки от разных серверов.

Не могу понять почему речь идет о файлах, а не о файле.

Comment: Это кажется для ситуации, когда куки разбиты на несколько файлов. Повторные вызовы задания этого параметра не перетирают предыдущее значение, а дополняют его. А еще эти файлы должны только читаться, а не записываться.

Comment: возможно я не правильно понял, но в этот файл, нужно и писать с помощью CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR и читать из Этого же файла с помощью CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE. А как по другому то ?

Comment: Вообще-то да, но в вопросе же `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` не упомянут и создается впечатление, что писалось посредством `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`

Comment: `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` это место куда будут сохранены данные после закрытия дескриптора curl.